# How to run code after test failure with testthat?

Tags: r, tdd, testthat

This is my test file:

```
## test-foo_files.R

## Setup
dir.create("temp")
file.create("temp/file1.R")
file.create("temp/file2.R")

## test
test_that("List all R files works", {
  expect_equal(list_R_scripts("temp"), c("file1.R", "file2.R"))
})

## Cleaning
unlink("temp")
```

How to make the cleaning part running even if the test fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from @Waldi is correct but thanks to him I have found a cleaner way to do it after some research.

It is called `fixtures` (see [here](https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/test-fixtures.html)) and works with the package `withr`.

`withr::defer()` solves some drawbacks of the `on.exit()` function.

One clean design to organize all that, is to use `setup-xxx.R` files like that:

```
## tests/testthat/setup-dir-with-2-files.R
fs::dir_create("temp")
fs::file.create(paste0("temp/", c("file1.R", "file2.R"))

withr::defer(fs::dir_delete("temp"), teardown_env())
```

And the test file is now:

```
## tests/testthat/test_list_r_scripts.R
test_that("List all R files works", {
  expect_equal(list_R_scripts("temp"), c("file1.R", "file2.R"))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `on.exit`:

```
## test-foo_files.R

## Setup
temp <- tempdir()
## Triggered cleaning
on.exit(unlink(temp))

file.create("file1.R")
file.create("file2.R")

## test
test_that("List all R files works", {
  expect_equal(list_R_scripts("temp"), c("file1.R", "file2.R"))
})
```